# Sum of multiples function 6Kyu Codewars

Tags: javascript

doing a codewars Kata - asks to write a function that takes a number, and extracts all multiples of 3 and 5 and adds them together. so if we pass 10 the result would be the sum of 3,5,6,9.

this is my code and I dont know why it isnt working:

```
function solution(number){
for (var i=0; i>=number; i++){
  if(i%3===0 || i%5===0){
  var arr = [];
  var full = arr.push[i];
  var sum= full.reduce(function(a,b){return a+b},0);
  console.log (sum);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `so 10 would be the sum of 3,5,6,9` How come? all the numbers inputed are the multiples of 3/5. The output should be 23. ^^

Comment: isn't 10 multiple of 3 or 5? so shouldn't it be the sum of 3,5,6,9, and 10?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues in your code

-- For-loop condition should be check less-than-equal rather than greater-than-equal

-- `sum` should be initialized in the beginning and `i` needs to be added to it if it satisfies the condition.

**DEMO**

```js
function solution(number)
{
   var sum = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<=number; i++)
   {  
       if( i%3===0 || i%5===0)
       {
           sum += i;
       }
   }
   return sum;
}
console.log( solution(10) );
```

If you **really** want to iterate the array only, then you need to fill the array first.

**DEMO**

```js
function solution(number)
{
   var sum = 0;
   var arr = Array( number ).fill().map( ( e , i ) => i+1 );   
   arr.forEach( function( item ){
       if( item%3===0 || item%5===0 )
       {
           sum += item;
       }
   });
   return sum;
}
console.log( solution(10) );
```

Comment: thankyou for this. so the way I was trying to do it - (where I tried to put all the values in an array and then add all the numbers of the array together) - is it possible for that to work? (even if its not the best way of doing it)?

Comment: @E.Moon You will first need to fill the array first from 1 to 10 and then iterate the same.